# Wordpress - Domain mapping problem on wordpress network

Tags: dns, wordpress

I'm having trouble with the setup of the MU domain mapping plugin, I'm just getting the default server cgi page when I goto the mapped domain. These are the steps I've gone through:

1. Installed the plugin and moved the sunrise.php into wp-content and and added the line in the wp-config.php file.
2. (All my domains are hosted by LCN) Added the "*" and the IP of my hosting to the main domain.
3. Added the IP for my mapped domain.
4. Added the new site in the super admin (although I can't find any files relating to this) - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/test/
5. Added my IP in the domain mapping configuration.
6. Added the mapped domain into the dashboard so it now shows where the root files are (even though there's no folder called that in my ftp) and the site it maps to.
7. When I load up the mapped site it just loads the default server cgi page at www.shareandbefair.com and a LCN parking page shareandbefair.com.

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a case of parking the mapped domain onto the main domain (where the network is).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your steps.  `sunrise.php` should be placed in the `/wp-content/` folder, not in wp-config.

You might want to walk through the step is [this tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/) for the MU domain mapping plugin.  The only thing that's changed between the tutorial and the current version is that you no longer move the `domain_mapping.php` file anywhere ... you just "network activate" the plugin instead.

If that still doesn't help, try this:

1. Make sure the domain to be mapped points to your existing WordPress installation.  If it doesn't point at WordPress, WordPress can't map it.
2. Make sure the domain is registered for the site you want to map it to using the MU domain mapping plugin (looks like you've already got this).
3. Make sure the domain is set as the primary domain for the site you want to map it to.
4. If that doesn't work, try poking the [WordPress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support), dropping in #wordpress on IRC, or try [Professional Domain Mapping](http://wpebooks.com/professional-domain-mapping/) instead ...

Comment: Oops, yep I meant the wp-content folder. I've gone through the tutorial you posted previously and no luck. The only thing I haven't tried is putting a cname line in the mapped domain as I'm not sure what my cname of the original site would be???

Comment: I've also tried the WP forums, they never seem to answer any questions I leave on there! http://wordpress.org/support/topic/trouble-with-mu-domain-mapping-plugin?replies=1